# How to do access and get data from a subcollection from Firestore in Flutter using Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

What code do I write in order to retrieve data from a subcollection in Firestore?

These are my collections and subcollection and the data fields in the subcollection document. I don't know the code for how to access this data from the document in the Running subcollection? Please help!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdCL2.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T89Gc.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4AC5.png)

Comment: Did you try anything yet?

Answer (score 0):

hey it's very easy to retrive subcollection :
Like this fuction

```
  getData() async {
return await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("Collectionname").doc("doc").collection("subcollection")
    .snapshots();
        }
```

Comment: What would be the data type of the getData() function, would it be a Future type because we don't if the user is going to create a running, swimming or weightlifting log?